# Keras permute_dimension causes weird tensor shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm running into an issue with a model I'm trying to build. I've been trying to debug it and ran into an oddity that I think may be the cause, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've reduced what I think the problem is into a small snippet you can run on colab.

Here's a colab where you can try running this:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pSTwCwMFGlWgJOP3gn9WF6pZq2CiP4XJ

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Layer, Dense, Input, Reshape
import keras.backend as K

class SimplePermute(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SimplePermute, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        return K.permute_dimensions(inputs, [0,2,1])
test_i = Input(shape=(10, 256))
test = SimplePermute()(test_i)
print(test.get_shape())
print(K.int_shape(test))
test = Dense(units=100, activation="softmax", name="sft2")(test)
print(test.get_shape())
print(K.int_shape(test))
```

I'd expect the second series of prints to print the permuted tensor shape - that is [?, 256, 10]. However, the K.int_shape() returns [?, 10, 256], while TF's get_shape() returns the properly permuted shape.

I believe this internal mismatch is causing the errors I'm seeing downstream in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom layer doesn't have the `compute_output_shape` method implemented. This is what Keras uses to determine the `_keras_shape` property of the tensors, which is returned by `K.int_shape`.

- You can use the standard `Permute((2,1))` layer.
- Or you can use a `Lambda(lambda x: K.permute_dimensions(x, [0,2,1]))` layer.
- Or you can implement the `compute_output_shape` method:

.

```
def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape): 
    return (input_shape[0], input_shape[2], input_shape[1])
```